# How to do an udapte with subquery and groupby?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, my first table named "popa" contains departments, my second table "stat" contains statistics, if I do an inner join of the 2 I get good results that I would like to put in a column "of" my table "popa".

```
SELECT dep, sum(i_d) FROM popa INNER JOIN stat on popa.num_dep = stat.dep group BY dep
```

I tried something like

```
UPDATE popa

SET pourcentagedeces = s from 

(SELECT dep as d, sum(i_d)as s
      FROM popa INNER JOIN stat on popa.num_dep = stat.dep group BY d)

WHERE dep = d
```

in fact i'm a little lost
as you can see i tried wht you said, but it didn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57b84.png)

Thank you stef

Comment: Why would you have a column to save calculated data? You should don't save a % or a SUM. What if the data change? You update every time? Why?

Comment: the data won't change, and i really need to save it for analysys

Answer (score 0):

You must use [multiple-table UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

```sql
UPDATE popa
JOIN (SELECT dep num_dep, SUM(i_d)as s
      FROM stat 
      GROUP BY num_dep) stats USING (num_dep)
SET popa.pourcentagedeces = stats.s;
```

Comment: that say Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''

Comment: @louisdefunes31 Check `stat.i_d`, `popa.num_dep` and `stat.dep` columns for empty string values... does some of them are VARCHAR?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments this is redundant storage of the aggregates but -

```sql
UPDATE `popa`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `dep`, SUM(`i_d`) AS `s`
    FROM `stat`
    GROUP BY `dep`
)AS `agg` ON `popa`.`num_dep` = `agg`.`dep`
SET `pourcentagedeces` = `agg`.`s`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

You use `UPDATE JOIN` where one p1 is the table and p2 is the subquery, joined by the condition.

```
   UPDATE popa p1 JOIN ( SELECT dep, sum(incid_dchosp) as s FROM popa INNER JOIN stat on popa.num_dep = stat.dep group BY dep ) p2 ON p1.dep = p2.dep
 SET p1.pourcentagedeces = p2.s
```

Comment: i tried to do it vut for some obscure reason there is an error near 'FROM'

Comment: @louisdefunes31 let me see your query. Are you using alias?

Comment: UPDATE p1

SET p1.pourcentagedeces = p2.s 

FROM
popa p1
JOIN (
SELECT dep, sum(incid_dchosp) as s FROM popa INNER JOIN stat on popa.num_dep = stat.dep group BY dep
) p2
ON p1.dep = p2.dep

Comment: @louisdefunes31 Please review my update. For mysql syntax is another one